# Problemas com retorno Botman + Httpful

Tags: php, laravel

Meu projeto consiste em um chatbot que recebe informações do usuario, consulta uma api criada por mim com essas informações, e deve apresentar para o usuario o retorno dessa consulta. Esse retorno é uma lista de JSON's.
Para criar o bot, estou utilizando o framework [Botman](https://botman.io/), e para fazer as requisições, a biblioteca [httpful](http://phphttpclient.com/).
Meu problema está na hora de apresentar o retorno para o usuário, que o botman não consegue apresentar.

Função:

```
public function pega_dados(){
    if($this->tipo == 'Produto'){ $aux = 1; }
    else { $aux = 2; }
    $uri = "localhost:7000/weight/?i=$aux&a=$this->descricao";
    $response = \Httpful\Request::get($uri)->send();

    $this->say($response->body[0]->id);

}
```

Este retorno que não está sendo apresentado: `$this->say($response->body[0]->id);`.

Se eu deixo apenas: `$this->say($response->body);`e faço uma solicitação que gere erro na minha API, ele retorna corretamente o erro. Caso contrario, não acontece nada e não tenho nenhum retorno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de tentar fazer o bot retornar o 'say' dentro desta função, tente o seguinte:

```
public function pega_dados(){
if($this->tipo == 'Produto'){ $aux = 1; }
else { $aux = 2; }
$uri = "localhost:7000/weight/?i=$aux&a=$this->descricao";
$response = \Httpful\Request::get($uri)->send();

return $response->body[0]->id;

}
```

E onde você chama a função `pega_dados()`, coloque o seu retorno em uma variável e printe a variável.

```
$aux= $this->pega_dados();
$this->say("$aux");
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado! Resolveu meu problema!